# BIRT Formatting Legend of a bar chart

Tags: java, eclipse, reporting, report, birt

I have a small problem, a BIRT report I designed uses a bar chart. Now I want to increase the space between colored box and the text in the legend. Is that possible? (I'm using BIRT 2.1.3)

http://www.fotos-hochladen.net/barchartproblemhng05e76.png

EDIT: I forgot to mention I am using BIRT 2.1.3 with the RCP Designer.

Comment: I forgot... ist BIRT 2.1.3 with the RCP Designer

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like that's possible. You can increase the space between the chart and the legend box, but there's no option to increase the space between the box and the text.

Perhaps you could try appending some spaces onto the series name when passing the data to BIRT (yes, that does sound like an awful workaround).